# Theoretical Space Station components

Tags: rocket-science

Having read some of the other answers and seeing that there is a theoretical maximum on payload with current technology, what would be the optimum dimensions of a space launch vehicle if all you wanted to do was use the empty shell to increase space on the [International Space Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station) (i.e. no satellites, no astronauts, no re-entry capability, just an empty shell)?.

Comment: Would [space.SE](http://space.stackexchange.com) be a better home for this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about space craft rather than physics. The [space.se] mods turned this down as being difficult to understand in its present form.

Answer (score 0):

Inflatable sphere component would give you most space

Comment: For stability/usefulness purposes, I doubt an *inflatable* component would be good, but likely a *collapsible* component could be good.

Comment: @TildalWave: I had completely forgotten about Bigelow, and they use *inflatable* to describe their modules. I suppose I think of inflatable as filling with air, like a balloon, and not collapsible/expandable like (I think) they intend.